# Task was destroyed but it is pending error

Tags: postgresql, python-3.6, python-asyncio, asyncpg

I have a class called engine.py which return connection pool.

```
class PIIEngine:

async def engine(self):
        self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
          config.pg_gdpr_contact_db_url)

        return self.pool
```

Then I have another module called model.py which has

```
def get_contacts(id):
    async def get(loop):
        conn = await engine.engine()
        async with conn.acquire() as txn:
           async with txn.transaction():
              stmt = """
                SELECT *
                FROM
                    <TABLE>
                WHERE
                    id = $1
            """

              contact =  await txn.fetchrow(stmt, id)

              if contact:
                  return dict(contact)
              else:
                  return None
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.ensure_future(get(loop))
    loop.close()
```

function `get_contacts` is called from swagger api but when I hit this api too many times I get

```
ERROR    - asyncio - Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<get_contacts.<locals>.get() running at 
/usr/src/models.py:2>>
```

Comment: You create a new pool each time `get` is called. You should either make a new connection each time or make the pool somewhere more persistent.

Comment: @dirn How do I do that? Because when I tried I get `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'DummyThread-1'.`

Comment: Right. You'd need to create the pool while the event loop is running. You'll either need to restructure your code to do that or switching to using single connections. It's not terribly obvious why you're using asyncio here, so another option is to change the code to be synchronous.

Comment: @dirn 
1. I'm using asyncio because asynpg only works with that.
2. I have updated code but I still get error per your suggestion. i now don't get too many connection error but I do get task pending. Can you please check whats wrong in it. I saw your other posts and tried  loop.cancel() but that didn't work either.

Comment: Change `asyncio.ensure_future(get(loop))` to `loop.run_until_complete(get(loop))`.

Comment: Why are you using asyncpg? The code you've shared doesn't benefit from it.

Comment: @dirn I'm trying to reduce processing time for API request which hit postgres. I used sqlalchemy(gave best results). Then I tried psycopg2 which reduced GET request but increased time for INSERTS(PUT). Now I'm trying asyncpg , trying to reduce time further.

Comment: It increased the time compared to what? Were you using a different Postgres driver or a different database? I suspect that you're spending a lot of time trying to save a few milliseconds, but the database is rarely the bottleneck in an application. With asyncpg, you're adding the overhead of an event loop with none of the benefits; you're running a single coroutine that will yield back to the loop, but there won't be anything else for the loop to run. I don't know if asyncpg is faster than psycopg2, but whatever you save is probably lost to the event loop.

Comment: @dirn Yes I agree with you. I think I'm wasting my time but once I started I had to make it work. I'm not seeing any performance increase with asyncpg. Thank you for your replies